# Resolve all data via local storage or api call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to come up with a single call to resolve numerous data objects before a controller is loaded.
I am using ui-router and am well aware of how to do a resolve, but I only need to load api objects if they are not available in local storage.  Below is some snippets of code i have in place

// Data Model that holds all the objects once resolved all loaded from local storage.

```
function TraqMetaDataModel() {

return {
  countries: [],
  brands: [],
};

TraqMetaDataLoader.load()

var traqMetaDataService = {
  load : load
};

return traqMetaDataService;

function load() {
  CountryLoader.fetchCountries(countrySuccess);
  BrandLoader.fetchBrands(brandSuccess);
}

function countrySuccess(response) {

  angular.forEach(LocalStorageHelper.get('countries'),function(value){
    TraqMetaDataModel.countries.push({CountryId : value.CountryId, Country : value.Country});
  });

}

function brandSuccess(response) {
  angular.forEach(LocalStorageHelper.get('brands'),function(value){
    TraqMetaDataModel.brands.push({BrandId : value.BrandId, BrandName : value.BrandName});
  });

}
```

I have all the logic to see if the item exists in localstorage and if not get from the api call. I guess im looking for a way to have a single call in the resolve function to check that the application state is ready to go.....

I will use an abstract route in ui route for the single call.

Be interested to see if anyone has done anything like this.

Thanks Rob

Comment: Are you looking to wait until the data is loaded and then proceed?

Comment: Im looking for the model to be populated with either data from local storage or the necessary api calls

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
If you don't find the data in local storage then fetch it using `$http`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = ["Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4"]

  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj, i){
    $http({method:'GET', url: 'http://httpbin.org/get', headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json"
 }}).
        success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      });
  });
}]);
```

Refer : http://plnkr.co/edit/cNDULiN02i430zl1zMpp?p=info

Comment: Thanks, but I have dealt finding the data and fetching it using $http. My problem is trying to find away all data is available before the controller resolves.  What I don't want is all individual resolves for each set of data.

Comment: can't you use service in that case? Services are singletons and initialized before controllers.